# How can I place Label over Button?

Tags: java, swt

The topic says it all, how can I place Label directly over Button? Tried multiple ways, nothing worked.. I can't use button.setTest("xxx"); in this case.

EDIT: I thought that mentioning SWT library in tags would be enough. I'm kind of ashamed for the code, therefore I didn't want to post it.

The thing is that I created ***a lot*** of buttons using for cycles, so I can't adress them by their variable name. My idea was creating another "layer" of labels and just have them over the buttons. The label should appear *after* the button is clicked.

```
MouseListener posluchac = new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseDown(MouseEvent me) {
        for (int k = 0;k<sirka;k++)
        {
            for (int l = 0;l<vyska;l++)
            {
                if(me.getSource() == cudliky[k][l])
                {
                    System.out.println(k +" "+ l);
                    Label lbl4 = new Label(cmpst2, SWT.NONE);
                    lbl4.setText("X");
                    lbl4.setBounds((990-sirka*25)/2+k*25,(800-vyska*25)/2+l*25,25,25);
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code creates labels, that are hidden.

Comment: button.setLabel("");

Comment: Please define 1. which framework you are using (swing, javafx, html, ...) 2. What exactly your problem is 3. Show us the code which causes the problem

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail about what you're trying to accomplish? Or more specifically, why you can't use `button.setText(String)`? You say you've "tried multiple ways", can you share those with us?

Comment: @Mohammad There is no `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button.setLabel(String)` method.

Comment: Creating a **lot** of anything will give you performance problems. Rethink your design.

Comment: Well, there isn't **a lot** of buttons, it just isn't specified right away. Their formation depends on user input...it should generate a playing board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to place a `Label` on top of the `Button` even if you don't want the button to have an initial text. This can all be achieved by using the right `Layout` or `LayoutData`. Here's an example using a `GridLayout` with 5 columns. The buttons initially don't have text on them, but do after you click on them (as you described in your question):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, true));

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        button.addListener(SWT.Selection, e -> button.setText(UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 10)));
    }

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    shell.setSize(600, 300);

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'd never figure out placing listener event right into for cycle :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo.

```
button.setText("xxx"); // works
```